# What is the region where $0 < z < 2 + (2-(x^2 + y^2))$?

Tags: integration

So, I'm trying to solve a problem where we have an intersection of two regions, one of them being $ 0 < z < 2-(x^2 + y^2)$.
At the first glance, I thought that that was the top part of the circumference defined by the equation above, added with a cylinder of equation $x^2 + y^2 = 2$.
But then I realized that if it was the answer, $z$ would be between $x^2 + y^2$ and $(2-(x^2+y^2))$.

So, now I have no idea of what region is this…

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2 < 2-z$, so for a fixed $z$ you have circles of radius up to $\sqrt{2-z}$ at height $z$. In other words a paraboloid, flipped upside down. See:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D2-z

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If we put
$$x=r\cos(t) \;,\; y=r\sin(t)$$
then

$$0<z<2-(x^2+y^2)$$
means that the point $(x,y,z)$ is above the plane $ z=0$ and
the surface $ z=2-r^2$ is a paraboloid of revolution.